# Create variable within a range of numbers except a list of numbers

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have the following variable with a list of numbers

```
vlist="1 13 20 21 22 24 25 28 240 131 133 136 138 224"
```

In the next loop I want to input a number between 1 - 250 except the numbers in vlist

```
while :; do
echo -en 'Number : ' ; read -n3 cvip ; echo
    [[ $cvip =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo -e '\nSorry input a number between 1 and 239 except '$vlist'\n' ; continue; }
    cvip=$(expr ${cvip} + 0)
    if ((cvip >= 1 && cvip <= 250)); then break ; else echo -e '\nNumber out of Range, input a number between 1 and 239 except '$vlist'\n' ; fi
done
```

Ηow can I enter the list exception inside the if statement range

Comment: Are you using `bash` or basic POSIX `sh`? You have both tagged, but your code includes bash-isms that don't work in sh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `bash`, one approach is to store the bad numbers as keys in an associative array and see if that particular key exists when validating a number:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

vlist="1 13 20 21 22 24 25 28 240 131 133 136 138 224"
declare -A nums
for num in $vlist; do
    nums[$num]=1
done

while true; do
    while read -p "Number: " -r num; do
        if [[ ! $num =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
            echo "Input an integer."
        elif [[ ${nums[$num]:-0} -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "Input a number between 1 and 250 except '$vlist'"
        elif [[ $num -lt 1 || $num -gt 250 ]]; then
            echo "Input an integer between 1 and 250"
        else
            break
        fi
    done
    printf "You successfully inputted %d\n" "$num"
done
```

The important bit is `${nums[$num]:-0}`, which expands to the value of that element of the associative array if that key exists and is not null, or 0 otherwise. As noted by Glenn in a comment, in `bash` 4.3 or newer, `[[ -v nums[$num] ]]` works too for testing to see if a given key exists, so `[[ ${nums[$num]:-0} -eq 1 ]]` in the above could be replaced with it.

Comment: with bash 4.3+, we can do `if [[ -v nums[$num] ]]` to see if that array key exists.

Comment: @glennjackman Ooo, nice. I missed seeing that addition.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I test it and it works just fine.